# Why am I getting ErrorException Notice Undefined variable when variable is set?

Tags: php, kohana

```
 class ControllerProduct extends Common {
 public function action_products()
 {

  $sellers_shop_id = '23';
  $this->template->content = View::factory('staff/seller_products')
   ->bind('sellers_shop_id', $sellers_shop_id )
   ->bind('catalogue', $tree )
   ->bind('alert', $this->alert );
```

view:

```
 &nbsp;<a href='/office/product/category_products/<?=$children['name'];?>/<?=$sellers_shop_id;?>' data-toggle='tooltip' title='продукты категории' class='trigg '>
```

err:
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: sellers_shop_id

```
var_dump( $this->template->content->sellers_shop_id ); // show var's content
```

and

```
$this->template->sellers_shop_id = $sellers_shop_id;
```

throw the same error.

Comment: are you absolutely sure to pass in the given controller ?

Comment: Yes, other variables passing to view normaly

Comment: Forgive me, for my carelessness. There was a foraech with a function in the view, I did not notice it. And fucntion did'nt know aboute this variable.